# Sharepoint: rename column (field) with C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, list, field

I want to rename a column (field) of some list with C#. How do I do this? Resetting 'Title' property or something else doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to change the actual column name or change the display title?

The first is not possible.. (unless you delete and re-create the column).
The display title yes, like the others said.

Answer (score 1):

There's some sample code for changing the title of a column here:

http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/fromthefield/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=0ce77946%2D1e45%2D4b43%2D8c74%2D21963e64d4e1&ID=15

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you update the field by calling its Update() method after setting the value. Can you post your code?